# Cannot hide ProgressBar programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am attempting to hide a `ProgressBar` after I load data to a `ListView`.  However, the `ProgressBar` does not seem to be effected by the view change.  I get no errors (`activityIndicator` does not appear to be `NULL`).  Is there something wrong with how I am going about this?

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/activityIndicator"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminateOnly="true"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

---

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    theInflater = inflater;
    theContainer = container;

    currentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_server_list, container, false);
    activityIndicator = (ProgressBar) currentView.findViewById(R.id.activityIndicator);

    // check if you are connected or not
    if(isConnected()){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                data.put("action", "getServerList");
                data.put("phone_id", "857a95839d7d6c270e97ff6a3a64008ccf96074ebffa6e8e82db932a6c635644");
                data.put("username", "atomic");
                data.put("password", "Pa55word1");
                AsyncHttpPost asyncHttpPost = new AsyncHttpPost(data);

                try {
                    String jsonString = asyncHttpPost.execute("http://website.com/app-files/API.php").get();

                    Log.i("JSON Result", jsonString);

                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);

                        if (json.optString("result").equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                            JSONArray articles = json.getJSONArray("data");

                            for (int i = 0; i < articles.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject row = articles.getJSONObject(i);
                                myServers.add(new Server(Integer.parseInt(row.getString("id")), 
                                        row.getString("host"), 
                                        0, //Integer.parseInt(row.getString("port")), 
                                        "", //row.getString("hostname"), 
                                        "", //row.getString("ipAddress"), 
                                        "", //row.getString("checkDate"), 
                                        "", //row.getString("serverInfo"), 
                                        "", //row.getString("lastModified"), 
                                        "", //row.getString("contentType"), 
                                        "", //row.getString("city"), 
                                        "", //row.getString("state"), 
                                        "", //row.getString("zip"), 
                                        "", //row.getString("country"), 
                                        "", //row.getString("latitude"), 
                                        "", //row.getString("longitude"), 
                                        "", //row.getString("timeZone"), 
                                        0, //Integer.parseInt(row.getString("consecutiveFails")), 
                                        Float.parseFloat(row.getString("latency")), 
                                        Float.parseFloat(row.getString("latency")) > 300 ? 
                                                R.drawable.btn_yellow : (Float.parseFloat(row.getString("latency")) > 1 ? 
                                                        R.drawable.btn_green : R.drawable.btn_red)));

                                //Log.i("Current Server's Host", row.getString("host"));
                            }

                            populateListView();

                            registerClickCallback();

                            currentView.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    activityIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        activityIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        Log.i("Connection", "You are NOT connected");
    }

    return currentView;
}
```

---

Edit: it seems that if I leave the tab and come back to the tab for this view the progress bar is gone.  So it's like it is removing the progress bar, but the view doesn't update to show that it's been reviewed.

Comment: is your application closing or not?

Comment: You are hiding the ProgressBar right after starting the Thread, and also inside the thread. Are you sure about this behaviour?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin No, the app does not crash.  It shows my list view just fine and I can scroll and click.  The only thing it is not doing is hiding the progress bar.

Comment: @AbhishekShukla Yes, I'm sure.  I'm just trying to get it to hide.  After than I can make it hide only after it needs to.  But it's not hiding at all, unfortunately.

Comment: Bad idea to put a progress bar in an xml. Better create one on the fly.

Comment: @greenapps Why is it better to create it on the fly?

Comment: Don't know but try and you will see. Just happened to me. Thats all.

Comment: @greenapps Do you mean you couldn't hide yours until you created it programmatically?

Comment: Something like that. Don't know anymore if it was about hiding. Anyhow it gave troubles. And please.. dont call a progressbar an activityindicator if you want readable code.

Comment: @James remove your thread and try to test it if your code for hiding the progress bar wrks.

Comment: YES... He has an asynctask in a thread. Good catch!!

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Actually, you can see it there again at the bottom where I am setting the view to `GONE` which is outside of the thread statement.  So I'm trying to do it twice and its not working in either place.

Comment: And now `status bar` ? Well create it on tje fly! Wenn will you try?

Comment: Stupid question: You confirmed that `isConnected()` returns true?

Comment: @HansKratz Yes, my list view populates correctly, which the functionality is only called if it returns true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think this is rather ridiculous, but here is how I fixed it.

In my xml for the `ProgressBar`, I added `android:visibility="gone"` to hide it by default.  Then, in my code, I first told it to display (`View.VISIBLE`) before it tried getting the server list, then I told it to hide (`View.GONE`) after it was done.  This worked (I could see the progress indicator while the data loaded, then it went away).  So I suppose I couldn't get it to hide in the code because the code is not what forced it to be visible to begin with...  That seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Wow you just saved me after I burned 2 hours on this. Just stupid. Thanks!