# How to start and stop progressbar in android?

Tags: java, android, progress

I have an activity that calls a second java class. I want after the second class is called to show a progressbar and then return to normal activity execution. I found some other threads but i couldn't make the progressbar to stop.

Comment: Could you please add you code to the question

Comment: you need to use progressdialog

Comment: so you can simply use `Visibility` gone and visible

Comment: You should provide more information. The relevant code should do it. 
You could most probably solve your problem with AsyncTask, but it could also be an overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a full example over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9814882/6203984).

Quote:

> Declare your progress dialog:
>
> ```
> ProgressDialog progress;
> ```
>
> When you're ready to start the progress dialog:
>
> ```
> progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "dialog title",
>     "dialog message", true);
> ```
>
> and to make it go away when you're done:
>
> ```
> progress.dismiss();
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Here's a little thread example for you:
>
> ```
> // Note: declare ProgressDialog progress as a field in your class.
>
> progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "dialog title",
>   "dialog message", true);
>
> new Thread(new Runnable() {
>   @Override
>   public void run()
>   {
>     // do the thing that takes a long time
>
>     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>       @Override
>       public void run()
>       {
>         progress.dismiss();
>       }
>     });
>   }
> }).start();
> ```

---

ProgressDialog is deprecated, so you might want to use a ProgressBar.

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24419407/6203984) about deleting one of them.

> Well, I think this is rather ridiculous, but here is how I fixed it.
>
> In my xml for the `ProgressBar`, I added `android:visibility="gone"`
>   to hide it by default.  Then, in my code, I first told it to display
>   (`View.VISIBLE`) before it tried getting the server list, then I told
>   it to hide (`View.GONE`) after it was done.  This worked (I could see
>   the progress indicator while the data loaded, then it went away).  So
>   I suppose I couldn't get it to hide in the code because the code is
>   not what forced it to be visible to begin with...  That seems like a
>   bug to me.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, @Pavneet_Singh. I'll do some more research and edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you this works fine. Suppose i want before dismissing the progress bar to make it visible for additional 20sec (the code runs too fast in localhost) to make the user undestand that something is in progress. How can i do that?

Comment: @tzimhspanousis, this might be something for an additional question. Post your code, too.

Comment: Ok. I posted a new question about the delay i was asking to add at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955349/how-to-show-progressbar-for-additional-20sec-in-android with the two scripts i need to manage.

Answer (score 1):

Its very Simple:

to show a Progress

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), "Title", "Message");
```

and to stop it:

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: `ProgressDialog`  has been deprecated, hence `ProgressBar` question

Comment: its deprecated? So What? You know that `Thread.stop()` is also deprecated since I've started programming? As long as there are a lot 4.X devices out it'll be guaranteed to still work.

Comment: `So What?` `Thread.stop()` is also deprecated  that's why nobody uses it and it's advisable in android that avoid deprecated version whenever possible and probably most knows about progress dialog start and stop but you can't do the same with progress bar hence the question